# af:convertNumber element removes zero in the end of the value

Tags: jsf, numbers, converters, oracle-adf

My code:

```
<af:inputText id="it1" label="Test">
   <af:convertNumber groupingUsed="true" type="number" messageDetailConvertNumber="#,###,##" maxFractionDigits="2"/>
</af:inputText>
```

When I type `100,51` -- everything is fine, but if I would type `100,50`, then '0' will be removed and entered value will be `100,5`. How can I leave this '0' in the end?

I need `<af:convertNumber>` element for other stuff and I need this '0' to be present. Any thoughts?

BR,
Raimonds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the property `maxFractionDigits="2"`, use  `minFractionDigits="2"` for this:

```
<af:convertNumber groupingUsed="true" type="number" 
                  messageDetailConvertNumber="#,###,##" 
                  maxFractionDigits="2" minFractionDigits="2"/>
```

Take a look at the [**JSF Converters Documentation**](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/j2ee101302/jsf_apps/eventvalidate/sf_avc_converters.html) for further information about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

```
messageDetailConvertNumber="###,###.00"
```